# No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: net_io_conectionclosed

Tags: .net, outlook

Utilizo vb.net
El siguiente código (para enviar correo mediante outlook) estaba funcionando bien hasta ayer, y hoy sale el error que adjunto en la imagen.

```
    Dim correo1 As New MailMessage
    Dim smtp1 As New SmtpClient()
    correo1.From = New MailAddress("yyyyyy@yyyyyy.es", "Yyyyyyyyy", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    correo1.To.Add("xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com")
    correo1.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    correo1.Subject = "CONTROL - ALERTAS "
    correo1.Body = "<p>Un cordial saludo.</p> <p> Sistema de Control</p>"
    correo1.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    correo1.IsBodyHtml = True '(formato tipo web o normal:  true = web)
    correo1.Priority = MailPriority.High  'prioridad
    smtp1.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("yyyyyyy@yyyyyyyy.es", "clave")
    smtp1.Port = 587
    smtp1.Host = "smtp.office365.com"
    smtp1.EnableSsl = True
    'ENVIO
    Try
        smtp1.Send(correo1)
    Catch ex As System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error al enviar correo!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
    correo1.Dispose()
```

Obviamente he cambiado las direcciones de correo y las passwords, pero están correctas.
El administrador me asegura que no hubo ningún cambio en la configuración del correo.
Agradezco anticipadamente cualquier idea.
Un cordial saludo.
Gabriel.
[image: ERROR]

Comment: Es posible que sea un problema de tls. Prueba con Tls1.2. Intenta añadir esto a tu codigo: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Answer (score 1):

Si, la solución es agregando tls al programa [como indica Pikoh en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514861/no-se-puede-escribir-datos-de-en-la-conexi%c3%b3n-de-transporte-net-io-conectionclos/526626#comment915022_514861). Lo probé y funciona bien:

> Es posible que sea un problema de tls. Prueba con Tls1.2. Intenta añadir esto a tu codigo:
>
> ```
> System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 –
> ```